# Discord js getting a bot's message

Tags: discord.js

Well i need to do this:
on a channel a bot announces "btc" price (not real)
im trying to get the price and send the price to a specificed channel
My code

```
sa.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("")) {
    if (message.author.id == "974187708933083157") {
      client.channels.get('955536998989447249').send(`${message.content}`);

    
    } else message.channel.send(``);
  }
})
```

So if a message that starts with  the bot needs to get the price and send it to the channel (955536998989447249)
But it not working my bot is working fine but not getting price and sendimg it

Comment: Unless you are running 2 clients in one file, either `sa.on` should be `client.on` or `client.channels` should be `sa.channels`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly don't try sending empty message ``` message.channel.send(``); ```, it will just throw an error.

The main problem, is that [client.channels (ChannelManager)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager) doesn't have a "get" method.

Assuming you are using djs v13, to get a channel, you can get it from cache with:

```js
client.channels.cache.get('955536998989447249').send("sth")
```

however this might not always work if the channel is not currently cached.
Other option is to fetch it, though it is an asynchronous operation, so it looks a bit different:

```js
client.channels.fetch('955536998989447249').then(channel => channel.send("sth"))
```